# Wrong implementation of $lookup from MongoDB in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an `Entity` model and a `Review` model, they are related by `entityId` field which is part `Review` model.

I am trying to find all the reviews from a specific `entity` and then calculate the average of all the rating of all reviews. (`rating` is another field of `Review` model, given below)

This is how `Entity` model looks:

```
const entitySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  }
});
```

and this is `Review` model:

```
const reviewSchema = new Schema({
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    required: true,
  },
  comment: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  public: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  entityId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Entity',
    required: true,
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

**I want to `$lookup` function here and this is what I have tried till now:**

```
router.get('/entities/reviews/average', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const entity = await Entity.find();
    const entityId = [];
    Object.keys(entity).forEach((key) => {
      entityId.push(entity[key]._id);
    });
    Object.keys(entityId).forEach((key) => {
      const reviews = Review.aggregate([
        { $match: { entityId: ObjectId(entityId[key]) } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'entity',
            localField: '_id',
            foriegnField: 'entityId',
            as: 'rating',
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            avg: { $avg: '$rating' },
          },
        },
      ]);
      res.send(reviews);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work it gives this response back

```
{
    "_pipeline": [
        {
            "$match": {
                "entityId": "5eb658d7"
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "entity",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foriegnField": "entityId",
                "as": "rating"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "avg": {
                    "$avg": "$rating"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {}
}
```

How to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting the reason behind that you are getting same query in return,

If i am not wrong then you are doing average of rating for entity, my suggestion is you can combine query and do it in single query,

- `$lookup` to join rating collection
- `$addFields` to do average, make array of rating using `$map` and then do average using `$avg`

```
router.get('/entities/reviews/average', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let reviews = await Entity.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Review",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "entityId",
                    as: "avgRating"
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    avgRating: {
                        $avg: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$avgRating",
                                in: "$$this.rating"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
        res.send(reviews);

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sAMp2jWkimO)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Lookup is doing a sql type join so the two fields you want to join on would have to match. I couldn't get you query working in mongo shell but I did get the following to work.

```
Reviews.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { entityId:  "5f56460d567f27054739c3bb"  },
            averageRating: { $avg: "$rating" },
          },
        },
      ])
```

It's run in mongo shell as well.